# Simplification of the statement of the spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 335 they state the spectral theorem for finite-dimensional inner product spaces:

> ***Theorem 9 (Spectral Theorem)***.
>   Let $T$ be a normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space $V$ or a self-adjoint operator on a finite-dimensional real inner product space $V$.
>   Let $c_1, \dotsc, c_k$ be the distinct characteristic values of $T$.
>   Let $W_j$ be the characteristic space associated with $c_j$ and $E_j$ the orthogonal projection of $V$ on $W_j$.
>   Then $W_j$ is orthogonal to $W_i$ when $i \neq j$, $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1, \dotsc, W_k$, and
>   $$
>   T = c_1 E_1 + \dotsb + c_k E_k.
> $$

Why in the beginning of the statement of this theorem can't we simply say

> Let $T$ be a normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner
>   product space $V$

and remove this part

> or a self-adjoint operator on a finite-dimensional real inner product
>   space $V$

since auto-adjunct operators on a finite-dimensional real inner product space is a normal one on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space.

**EDIT**

Answering the comments asking why an auto-adjunct operator is a normal one: If an operator $T$ is auto-adjunct, then $T^*=T$ and particularly $T^*T=TT^*$, so it's normal.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain how exactly an "auto-adjunct operators on a finite-dimensional real inner product space is a normal one on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space".

Comment: @JendrikStelzner If an operator $T$ is auto-adjunct, then $T^*=T$ and particularly $T^*T=TT^*$, so it's normal.

Comment: I should have been more specific: If $T$ is a selfadjoint operator on a __real__ inner product space $V$, then $T$ is in particular a normal operator on this __real__ inner product space $V$; this much (I think) is clear. But you seem to claim that $T$ is (in some way) a normal operator on some __complex__ inner product space, and I don’t see where this complex structure comes from. (At least not without some rather lengthy arguments via extension of scalars.)

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Every real inner product space $V$ is a complex one, no? since $\mathbb R\subset \mathbb C$.

Comment: One can complexify a real inner product space $V$ to get a complex inner product space $V_\mathbb{C}$, and if $T \colon V \to V$ is a self-adjoint operator then we get a self-adjoint operator $T_\mathbb{C} \colon V_\mathbb{C} \to V_\mathbb{C}$. But I don’t think there is a way to regard $V$ itself as a complex inner product space (or even a complex vector space).

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Thank you for trying to help me, but I really didn't understand your point. As I said, since $\mathbb R\subset \mathbb C$ we can see the elements of $\mathbb R$ as elements of $\mathbb C$. So the real scalar elements of the vector space $V$ are elements of $\mathbb C$. Thus every real vectorial space is a complex one. Which points I'm mistaken?

Comment: A vector space does not consists of scalars, so talking about "the real scalar elements of the vector space $V$" makes no sense.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Let me make myself clear. The difference between an real vector space and a complex space is because in the complex case you can multiply vectors by complex numbers instead of only real ones. Since the real numbers are complex ones, we can say that real vector spaces are complex ones. Are you following me? thank you

Answer (score 2):

The proof of the theorem requires that *V* have an orthonormal basis consisting of characteristic vectors (eigenvectors) of *T*. For a finite-dimensional inner product space over the field of *complex* numbers, such a basis exists if and only if *T* is normal. There are some normal operators, however, that have no such basis if the space is over the field of *real* numbers; for example, the matrix representation of one such operator is
$${\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}.$$
For a finite-dimensional inner product space over the field of real numbers, *V* has an orthonormal basis consisting of characteristic vectors of *T* if and only if *T* is *self-adjoint,* a more restrictive requirement than normality. Hence, the authors separated the complex and real cases in the hypothesis of the theorem to keep it sharp for each case.

See pages 335–336 in [*Linear Algebra*](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) for the spectral theorem and its (short) proof. See the first two paragraphs of Section 8.5 (pages 311–312) for the source of my answer.