# Understanding Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I got the proof from mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289112/730490).

> **Spectral Theorem**: Let $T$ be a normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space $V$ or a self-adjoint operator on a finite-dimensional real inner product space $V$.
>   Let $c_1, \dotsc, c_k$ be the distinct characteristic values of $T$.
>   Let $W_j$ be the characteristic space associated with $c_j$ and $E_j$ the orthogonal projection of $V$ on $W_j$.
>   Then $W_j$ is orthogonal to $W_i$ when $i \neq j$, $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1, \dotsc, W_k$, and
>   $$
>   T = c_1 E_1 + \dotsb + c_k E_k$$

**Proof**: Let $\alpha$ be a vector in $W_j$, $\beta$ a vector in $W_i$, and suppose $i\neq j$. Then $c_j⟨\alpha,\beta⟩=⟨T\alpha,\beta⟩=⟨\alpha,T^*\beta⟩=⟨\alpha,\overline{c_j}\beta⟩$. Hence $(c_j-c_i)⟨\alpha,\beta⟩=0$, and since $c_j-c_i\neq 0$, it follows that $⟨\alpha,\beta⟩=0$. Thus $W_j$ is orthogonal to $W_i$ when when $i\neq j$. $\color{red}{\text{From the fact that } V \text{ has an orthonormal basis consisting of characteristic vectors, it}}$ $\color{red}{\text{follows that }V=W_1+\cdots+W_k}$. If $\alpha_j$ belongs to $V_j(1\leq j\leq k)$ and $\color{red}{\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k\stackrel{?}{=}0}$, then
\begin{align}
0&\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{=}}(\alpha_i,\sum_j\alpha_j)=\sum_j(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)\qquad(1)\\
&=\|\alpha_i\|^2
\end{align}
For every $i$, so that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1,\cdots,W_k$. Therefore $\color{red}{E_1+\cdots+E_k=I}$ and 
\begin{align}
T&=TE_1+\cdots+TE_k\\
&=c_1E_1+\cdots+c_kE_k
\end{align}

---

I am not a follower of **Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra** but for seeking my proof of Spectral Theorem I read that part. And I didn't manage to understand the red marked line. Like:
$(1)$ Why $V$ space can be written as a sum of the $W_i$ space$?$
$(2)$ Why the sum of the vectors $\alpha_i$ is zero$?$
$(3)$ Why the equality hold for $(1)?$
$(4)$ Why the sum of eigenvectors $E_i$ is $I?$
Maybe all of my question require another reference theorem but I really want to know all of those **Why**.
Thanks for your time and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(1) If you assume known that there is a basis of eigenvectors, then any vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors, and since any eigenvector belongs to some $W_i$, the result follows.

(2) This is an *assumption* made in order to prove that the sum is direct.

(3) This holds because it's the inner product of two vectors, the second of which is zero (see (2)).

(4) $E_i$ is not a vector, it's a projection onto the eigenspace $W_i$. Since the sum of eigenspaces is direct, if you take a basis for each $W_i$ then these bases make up a basis of $V$, the matrix of $E_i$ in this basis is going to be diagonal with $1$'s at the $W_j$ entries and $0$ elsewhere, and the sum of these matrices is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Arnaud Mortier. $\alpha_i\in V_i$ so $\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k$ is a vector which lie in $V_1+\cdots+V_k(\text{Am I right}?)$ Then why we are assuming it should be zero to prove $V=V_1+\cdots+V_k(\text{This is I mean by the sum is direct})?$

Comment: @NajmunNahar To prove that a sum is direct, by definition you need to show that if a sum of vectors from each space is zero, then every vector has to be zero already.

Comment: Got it(+1). however I convince myself that $E_iE_j=0;i\neq j$ but I didn't get any link to convince myself that $(E_i)^2=E_i$ @Arnaud Mortier. That my last question. I will close this thread accepting your answer than

Comment: @NajmunNahar $E_i$ was *defined* to be a projection, so $E_i^2=E_i$ holds by definition.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

$$ P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac1{\sqrt2} &  \frac1{\sqrt2} \\
0 & \frac1{\sqrt2} & -\frac1{\sqrt2} \\
1 & 0              & 0 
\end{pmatrix};\;
T = P
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
P^T =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 & -\frac32 & 0 \\
-\frac32 & \frac12 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

There are two eigenvalues: $c_1 = -1$ and $c_2 = 2$. The orthogonal projections are

\begin{align}
E_1 &= P
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}P^T =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 \\
\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \\
E_2 &= P
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}P^T =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 & -\frac12 & 0 \\
-\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

This works in general. To obtain $E_i$, you take $T = PDP^T$ and replace all the eigenvalues in $D$ by $1$ if they equal $c_i$ and $0$ if they are a different eigenvalue.

You should convince yourself that

1. $$ E_1 + E_2 + \dots + E_k = P
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
   \end{pmatrix} P^T = I.
   $$
2. $$ c_1 E_1 + c_2 E_2 + \dots + c_k E_k = PDP^T = T. $$
3. $E_i$ projects onto the $c_i$-eigenspace. For a start: if you multiply $P$ times the modified diagonal matrix, the remaining columns of $P$ are a basis for the $c_i$-eigenspace, in particular the column space (image) of $E_i$ is contained in the $c_i$-eigenspace.

Comments:

1. This is all easy to see if you just don't write the $P$'s and $P^T$'s and just write the matrices in terms of the eigenbasis rather than the standard basis.
2. This works for any diagonalizable matrix, if you replace $P^T$ by $P^{-1}$. I'm just using a self-adjoint (i.e. symmetric) operator because that's what the Spectral Theorem applies to. For self-adjoint matrices the special facts are: 1) they are always diagonalizable 2) we can diagonalize them with an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your demonstration. I need some help on your point $3$. Like **the remaining columns of $P$ are a basis for the $c_i$-eigenspace**. Do you mean the resultant matrix$(E_i)$ and it's first two column$?$

Comment: I found that $(E_1)^2=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=E_1$ why this happening$?$ and $E_1E_2=0$

Comment: @NajmunNahar $E_i$ projects onto the $c_i$-eigenspace. That means that $E_i v = v$ if $v$ is in the $c_i$-eigenspace and $E_i v = 0$ if $v$ is orthogonal to the $c_i$-eigenspace. There exists, by the spectral theorem, an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors. Therefore if $v_i$ is in the $c_i$-eigenspace and $v_j$ is in the $c_j$-eigenspace, then $v_i$ is orthogonal to $v_j$. Thus $E_i v_j = 0$ since $v_j$ is orthogonal to the $c_i$-eigenspace. Given this orthonormal basis, you can check directly that $E_i^2 = E_i$ and $E_i E_j = 0$.

Comment: @NajmunNahar I mean if the columns of $P$ are $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and $v_1, v_2$ are a basis for the $c_1$-eigenspace, then when I construct $E_1$, I'm taking $P \operatorname{diag}(1,1,0) P^T = (v_1, v_2, 0) P^T$. By multiplying by this diagonal matrix, I'm leaving only the columns of $P$ that are in the appropriate eigenspace.